# Displaying figures from RMarkdown with github_document output

Tags: r, r-markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I am trying to display figures on github  from RMarkdown without success.

- The figure is displayed on the local html preview.
- After pushing on Github the md file the figure is not displayed.

---

```
title: "Untitled"
output: github_document
```

---

```
summary(cars)

plot(pressure)
```

Comment: Can you show the resulting syntax of the .md file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to push the images files containing figures too.